# Select first row in each group in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to translate a question to sql type.The question is this:
"Most successful SKU in terms of revenue (in USD) per country"
So i need the best selling product for each country

My data look like this:

```
,Platform,Userid,In-app Product,Country,Currency,Timestamp,Transaction Receipt,Price
0,IOS,5.669802981,offer4,US,USD,28/03/2017 02:30,240200367307.75848,1.99
1,ANDROID,6.831350998,offer4,US,USD,27/03/2017 23:23,436138823984.4136,3.99
2,ANDROID,6.831233793,pack2.cash,CA,USD,27/03/2017 18:32,192318559985.1093,4.112
```

This is what i have tried

```
select Sum("Price"),"In-app Product","Country" from cleandataset group by "Country","In-app Product" order by "sum" desc,"Country"
```

The problem is i dont know how to get only the first row from each group.Any help would be appreciated!

My query right now produce something like this:

```
sum                In-app Product Country
2578.591999999975   "offer4"    "US"
1917.3325600000014  "offer10"   "US"
1885.1750599999978  "pack4.shields" "US"
1387.155899999998   "pack3.shields" "US"
1200.6980999999992  "offer10"   "FR"
1150.638300000004   "offer4"    "FR"
811.1277999999998   "pack4.shields" "FR"
790.5170000000022   "offer4"    "IT"
773.3864000000004   "offer10"   "ES"
763.307199999999    "pack2.shields" "US"
735.6938099999996   "pack3.cash"    "US"
702.2611000000019   "offer4"    "ES"
701.3979000000004   "offer10"   "IT"
675.4060400000003   "offer15"   "US"
672.7070000000007   "pack3.shields" "FR"
660.80911   "pack5.shields" "US"
```

So i think i need to select the Product with the biggest sum in each country

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: @NathanHughes unfortunately not

Comment: @xaroulisgekas your query produces duplicates for each country ? and you need just 1 row per each ?

Comment: @trillion i edit my question.Take a look

Comment: @xaroulisgekas so you need the row with just the highest sum of price  per country and product ?

Comment: @trillion Exactly

Comment: @xaroulisgekas can you check the solution below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236814/discussion-between-trillion-and-xaroulis-gekas).

Comment: @trillion i am in the chat

Comment: @xaroulisgekas join again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on` directly with `group by`:

```
select distinct on ("Country") Sum("Price"), "In-app Product", "Country"
from cleandatase
group by "Country", "In-app Product"
order by "Country", Sum("Price") desc;
```

Note:  As Thorsten points out, if there are ties and you want all the ties, then `distinct on` is not the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

- Calculate sum per app product and country
- Create a rank based on sum calculated in step 1 in the DESC order which means we are ranking from top to bottom starting with the largest sum valye
- choose rank = 1 to get rows with the highest sum, eliminating the duplicates

```
with total as (
select 
    Country,app_product, sum(price) over(partition by country,app_product) as total
from [table]  
)
,
ranking as (
select
 *, row_number() Over(Partition by country by total desc) as rank_
from total_
)
select 
country, app_product, total from ranking where rank_ = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunatly its doent run.I use pgadmin for the queries.It says that it have synstax error near of the select

Comment: @xaroulis gekas: In case of ties this query picks one of the top products per country arbitrarily. If you want to show all top #1 products, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` by `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it using a `ROW_NUMBER` function with `PARTITION BY` Product, Country and select the ROW_NUMBER = 1

See https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/

Comment: i saw that but i dont know how to use it on my example

Comment: if you are not providing a solution then use comment instead of answer

Comment: see the example of @trillion

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Use your query and `distinct on` :

```sql
select distinct on (country) * 
from 
(
  select country, app_product, sum(price) as "sum" 
  from the_table
  group by country, app_product
) as t
order by country, "sum" desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

While PostgreSQL has `DISTINCT ON` to get only one row per group, this often doesn't suffice, because it cannot deal with ties. If two products in a country have the same top total, then you'll probably want to show both.

You can use this standard SQL query instead:

```
select
  country,
  in_app_product,
  sum(price) as total
from cleandataset
group by country, in_app_product
order by rank() over (partition by country order by total desc)
fetch first row with ties;
```

Or this:

```
select country, in_app_product, total
from
(
  select
    country,
    in_app_product,
    sum(price) as total,
    max(sum(total)) over (partition by country) as max_total
  from cleandataset
  group by country, in_app_product
)
where total = max_total;
```

And there are still other ways to do this.